# Reference static global variable from a different file

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm trying to understand static global variables. I've read that the `static` keyword makes a global variable "private", accessible only from the file it's been defined.

To test this I created a couple of files.
`file1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.c"

extern int a;
extern int b;

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", a);
  printf("%d\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

And `file2.c` which consists only of the global variable definitions. One static and the other not to compare:

```
int a=1;
static int b=2;
```

After compiling `file1.c`, the output is:

```
1
2
```

Since `b` is static, I expected that it shouldn't be accessible from `file1.c`. Yet after declaring it with `extern int b`, `file1.c` was able to print it.

I thought static variables couldn't be accessed from other files. Why was I able to access a `static` variable from a different file?

Comment: _Do not include `.c` files_.

Comment: You don't use `#include` to combine `.c` files. You compile each of them to a `.o` object, then you combine them with the linker.

Comment: `static variables couldn't be accessed from other files` That's correct, but there is no "*other files*" here because of the `#include "file2.c"`. The compiler sees just one [translation unit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) which is based on `file1.c`. That part of the code has been "pasted" from `file2.c` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that the `static` keyword makes a global variable "private", accessible only from the file it's been defined.

That is approximately correct, but very misleading if you don't recognize that the word "file" is being used as a simpler stand in for the more correct term "translation unit".  The latter can be viewed as the composite code formed from a source file by (pre)processing all the `#include` and conditional-inclusion directives within.  That forms one logical unit of source code for compilation ("translation" in the standard's terminology).

Thus, when one talks about static declarations being scoped to one file, one means a file intended to be the main file of a translation unit. We thereby identify the TU with that file.  This is in fact the essential difference between header files (.h) and source files (.c) -- both contain C source code, but the latter are meant to be compilation starting points, whereas the former are not.  That's also why one should never `#include` a .c file.

> I thought static variables couldn't be accessed from other files. Why
> was I able to access a static variable from a different file?

Because you're interpreting "file" differently than it was meant in the claim you're referring to, and because you have violated the strong convention supporting that word usage by `#include`ing one .c file into another.  You are compiling just one translation unit, and all file-scope declarations of all contributing files (filesystem sense) are visible within.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the correct way of including file2 would be by using a header file. I'm still learning about working with multiple files and using header files. If it's not too much asking, could you show in your answer how would  a header file look in this case to include file2 from file1.c "correctly"?

Comment: @fabrizzio_gz, if you mean for the second file to be used as a header -- that is, `#included` in other files -- then change its name to `file2.h` and `#include` it under that name.  But note that that will not in itself change the behavior of your program in any way.

Comment: I meant to create a third header file that would link file1.c to file2.c "correctly", but maybe that's not the way to do it. I guess I need to research more on this topic.

Comment: @fabrizzio_gz, no, that's not the way to do it.  "Linking", in this sense, is an operation performed as part of compiling programs.  It is not an observable characteristic of source code.  Very likely your compiler would do it for you if you just name both source files on the compiler's command line, though that's not usually the only way to do it.

Comment: I believe I was able to produce the result I was looking for by creating a header file with the global variable declarations, `#include`ing the header on both `.c` files and them compiling it all with: `gcc file1.c file2.c -o main`. The output for the static variable was `0`. Since it was initialized to `2`, I guess `file1.c` wasn't able to access it and printed `0` somehow.